# How to align center Wordpress plug-in contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, contacts, contact-form-7

The topic says it all. I've been trying various code propositions from various websites with no success.

This is the site: http://jakubplech.pl/kontakt-copywriting-slask/

The form is in the bottom, i'll be glad for any help. Please mind that i don't want to play with padding or margin - it should align to center on any device used to visit the site.

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it was way easier than i thouth - the solution is a simple

```
div.wpcf7 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Aligning the text in wordpress page editor did not work - it had to be done in the additional CSS space.

div.wpcf7 refers to the whole designer contact sheet. Loks like working during late hours is not always a good idea :)